# App_Data folder shadow folder empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, csv

I am coding in `ASP.net` using C# in Visual Studio 12. In my `App_Data` folder, I have a `first.csv` file that contains some numerical data.

I received another file called `second.csv` which is slightly different from the first file. It contains an extra column.

I was using `linq` to read the csv file

```
 var idata = from line in File.ReadAllLines("second.csv").Skip(0) 
                          let parts = line.Split(',') 
                          select new  
                          { 
                              Date_ = parts[0],
                              Year_ = parts[1], and so on
```

I had deleted the `first.csv` file from the `App_Data` folder and pasted the `second.csv` file. When I run my code, the program seem to be reading the old values from the `first.csv` file instead of reading the `second.csv` file values.

In my code I had added an extra column that was in the `second.csv` file. But my program still reads the values from the `first.csv` file that does not exist in the `App_Data` folder. Could someone please guide me with what I'm doing wrong.?

I have looked at the shadow folder in the microsoft .net folder in C drive but it turned out to be empty. What can I do? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Clear history of browser before run the program.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had tried everything(even clearing the history) except one thing which I think is the answer. I will post it up, give me a few minutes. It works now :)

Comment: Nice to hear dat... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After numerous suggestion from several users ranging from updating the shadow folders to clearing the history and rebuilding the solution, I think the solution that worked for me was as follows:

I wrote another piece of code which performed the same function as previous code but this time **I read a different file**. When I ran the code, it was supposed to work but it didn't and produced an error saying
 `"Could not find the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\testFile.csv'"`

Now when I went to that folder, I found that the "first.csv" was there but "second.csv" file wasn't which meant that I needed to place a copy of the "second.csv" file here for the first attempt to work properly.

So I basically got a copy of "second.csv" and pasted it into the folder and ran my code. It gave me the correct output as I had suspected.